# Fail to convert pandas type from 'object' to 'string'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, types, dtype

This question seems very basic and the topic was clearly answered in this question :
[Change data type of columns in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15891038/change-data-type-of-columns-in-pandas)

I have a DataFrame `df`.
One column is named `adress` and contains strings :

```
type(df.loc[0, 'adress'])
>>> str

#Let's check the whole column's type

df.loc[:, 'adress'].dtype
>>> dtype('O')
```

The dtype is an object, I would like to change it to a string. 
I tried :

```
df.loc[:, 'adress'] = df.loc[:, 'adress'].astype(str)
df.loc[:, 'adress'].dtype
>>> dtype('O')

#and

df.loc[:, 'adress'] = df.loc[:, 'adress'].astype('str')
df.loc[:, 'adress'].dtype
>>> dtype('O')

#and

df = df.infer_objects()
df.loc[:, 'adress'].dtype
>>> dtype('O')
```

I have no idea what I am missing.

I aslo checked that the whole column contains only strings :

```
for i in df.index:
    if type(df.loc[i, 'adress']) != str:
        print(i)
        wait = input('Up')
print('Done')
>>>Done
```

Comment: if you use pandas>=1.0, then you can try `df['adress'].astype('string')`, see [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html#text-types) and you will get [`StringDtype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.StringDtype.html#pandas.StringDtype). prior this version then column with string could be only `object`